# What is the inverted output for on a D flip flop?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, latch, logic-gates

I was asked to find the answer for this, it is a pretty vague question:

**On a D Flip Flop, what is the Q' output? Look this up and write your answer in your pre-lab report.**

I am trying to understand the circuit, it looks like Q' is what retains the previous value of Q when the clock is high. Can someone explain more about this to me?

Answer (score 3):

Very fundamental thing. Flip-flops are composed of logic circuits that have cross coupled feedback such that they "hold" the last established state. These bi-stable circuits are often composed of inverting gate elements that invert twice around their cross coupled feedback to realize the latched state.

Simply the Q output is the output of one side of the bi-stable circuit. The Q' is the other output which, in the case of cases where inverted logic elements are used, ends up being the logical inversion of the Q output.

So if Q = 1 the Q' = 0. Likewise of Q = 0 the Q' = 1.

Comment: So I can say that Q' will contain the inverse of the value of D in the previous cycle and that is also the feedback used for Q in the present cycle?

Comment: Yes. There is no absolute requirement to bring this out to the pins of an IC, but in general a "pre-inverted" version of the Q output is so useful that it's brought out as a matter of course.

Comment: @JOX - You have to stop thinking of the Q' as a history element. For your typical 74xx74 type D flip flop that has both Q and Q' outputs it is simply that Q attains the value of the D input after the clock and the Q' attains the inverted value of the D input after the clock. Of course the D input must meet setup and hold time requirements for the particular FF in use.

Comment: Normally the Q' output will be the inverse of the Q at least after a propagation delay following the clock. Things might be different if the FF has reset and set inputs and they're both active (The 74HC74 will have *both* outputs high as long as that condition exists).